# Laravel Migrations change/update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-5.1

How do I properly change / update my migration, I am using Laravel 5.1.

The Docs said that I should use change to update the column e.g.:

```
$table->string('color', 10)->change();
```

But where do I have to put it in the migration and what command do I have to use to update just a simply php artisan migrate?

I tried this so far:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table)) {
        $table->string('color', 5);
   });

   Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table)) {
        $table->string('color', 10)->change();
   });
}
```

And used this command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

But it did not change.

Comment: You can use `artisan` to generate a migration file for you `php artisan make:migration yourmigrationname`

Answer (score 10):

First, create new migration to change existing table column(s).

```
php artisan make:migration update_products_table
```

Then you should do this inside `up()` method in your new migration:

```
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('color', 10)->change();
});
```

So, you'll have two migrations. First did already create `products` table with wrong length of the `color` string.

Second migration will change `color` string length from 5 to 10.

After you created seconds migration, run `php artisan migrate` again and changes will apply to a table.

Comment: Thus should I let the down method of that new migration let be empty

Comment: I get an error after doing this syntax rror, unexpected '>', expecting '<'

Comment: Please post full error message. I bet it's an error somewhere inside you app code.

Comment: `[Symfony\Components\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
syntax error, unexpected '>', expecting '<'`

Comment: This error could be in any of you files like Controllers, Models, routes etc. Please check all files which you did edit recently.

Comment: hmm really hard to find :)

Comment: if I delete the code in the new migration it works, but I do not see any mistakes there

Comment: do you know if this ->unsigned()->change(); make a difference

Comment: `unsigned()` is used for integers, not for strings. If you don't use it for `tinyInteger`, for example, you can use numbers from -128 to 127. If you use it, you can use numbers from 0 to 255. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: oh sorry I used it for an integer I have more fields just than color

Answer (score 4):

You might use `php artisan migrate:refresh` to recreate the table (after editing the original migration).

Beware, it deletes your tables ! Useful for a quick fix on a new install though

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd sum up what I did to achieve this, to elaborate on the answer above.

```
php artisan make:migration change_yourcolumn_to_float_in_yourtable
```

Then, inside of that migration, in the `up()` method, I added something like the following:

```
Schema::table('yourtable', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->float('yourcolumn')->change();  // Changing from int to float, ie.
});
```

Then you may need to add a package, to make database modifications like this:
Enter into the console: `composer require doctrine/dbal`

Then you can go ahead and `php artisan migrate` to commit the change.